# How to mention non-archival CS workshop publications on resume

Tags: publications, cv

I'm a new PhD student in a CS-related research area with a very limited number of publications. As part of working on my current research projects I've managed to get some non-archival publications at workshops of top tier conferences to show my work in progress.

These non-archival publications range from 3 to 8 pages and contain enough good content to make it into a decent number of mid-range journals/conferences. I'd say that this is quite different from what you would know from workshop publications in e.g. social science, and I would therefore like advice from others with a similar research field to mine.

I'd like to show this work on my academic resume, but what is the preferred approach? Should I list it alongside my "real" publications and mark each one of them with a note saying it was non-archival, should I list them separately or should I do something completely different?

**Edit:**

Things are a bit complicated as I also have 2 recent non-archival papers from a more tangential field to CS. These papers are not workshop papers, but similar in scope in terms of amount of content. I guess I also need to fit these in the same category. Note that some of my non-archival papers involve presentations and some posters.

Answer (score 2):

List your contributions as accepted *presentations* for workshops, not as publications, and make a separate list for presentations of this sort. For the more tangential contributions, ask yourself if they are important to mention on your resumé. If they are indeed important, then you may want to group your presentations according to the subject area.